# Рекурсия в Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Здравствуйте.

Разрабатываю скрипт который открывает пустые клетки, от выбранной клетки, во все стороны, до тех пор пока не наткнется на заполненные клетки. Это подобное тому что есть в игре "Сапер", когда нажимаете на пустую клетку и у вас открываются все соседние пустые клетки. Ничего лучше чем рекурсия придумать не смог.

Вот код рекурсии:

```
function openWhite(col, row)
    if(_cubCol[col][row]~=nil)then
        if(_cubCol[col][row][2]==CLEAR)then
            _cubCol[col][row][1].isVisible = False
            openWhite(col, row+1)
            openWhite(col, row-1)
                    openWhite(col+1, row)
            openWhite(col-1, row)
            openWhite(col+1, row+1)
            openWhite(col+1, row-1)
            openWhite(col-1, row+1)
            openWhite(col-1, row-1)
        end
    end
end
```

Но данная функция зацикливается уже на 2-ом вызове самой себя "openWhite(col, row-1)".

Вот ошибка

[image]

Подскажи что я не так делаю? И можно ли как то обойтись без рекурсии?

И если не сложно, подскажите нормальную IDE в которой можно дебажить скрипты Lua, для Corona SDK?

Comment: По поводу ухода вашей функции в бесконечность: Вы не делали проверку на то, что уже прошлись по ячейке. То есть при openWhite(col, row+1) шел проход вправо, а потом начинался вызов openWhite(col, row-1) и шел проход по ячейкам влево, которые вы уже прошли. Поэтому уже первые два вызова взаимно зацикливались.

Comment: Alex Krass, Спасибо. Ваша подсказка и ваш ответ, то что надо для моей рекурсии. Стоило добавить проверку на то, что уже проходился по ячейке и всё заработало как надо :-) Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, что бы сделать без рекурсии, нужен будет контейнер для хранения не проверенных пустых клеток и запоминать, какие клетки уже были пройдены. Для хранения можно воспользоваться массивом, а для проверки условием _cubCol[dCol][dRow][2] == CLEAR and             _cubCol[dCol][dRow][1].isVisible == True (соседняя клетка пуста, но еще не обработана). При таком условие можно добавить клетку в массив на обработку.

Соответственно, алгоритм такой:

1. Изначально забиваем в контейнер первую ячейку
2. Если размер контейнера больше нуля входим в цикл
3. Выбираем первый элемент и удаляем
       его из контейнера
4. Проделываем необходимые манипуляции
       с ячейкой
5. Проверяем соседние ячейки и при
       необходимости добавляем их в
       контейнер

Язык LUA не знаю, но код должен быть такой по идее:

```
function point(col,row)
  return {col,row};
end

checkArr = {};
table.insert(checkArr,point(1,1)); # точка входа, для примера (1,1)

while #checkArr>0 do
  local point = checkArr[1];
  table.remove(checkArr, 1);

  if _cubCol[point.col][point.row]~=nil and _cubCol[point.col][point.row][2]==CLEAR then
    _cubCol[point.col][point.row][1].isVisible = False;

    if _cubCol[point.col][point.row+1][2]==CLEAR and _cubCol[point.col][point.row+1][1].isVisible == True then
      table.insert(checkArr,point(point.col,point.row+1));
    end
    if _cubCol[point.col][point.row-1][2]==CLEAR and _cubCol[point.col][point.row-1][1].isVisible == True then
      table.insert(checkArr,point(point.col,point.row-1));
    end
    ... etc
  end
end
```

Данный пример не оптимальный, но самый простой.

UPD: Я еще забыл добавить проверки для прилежащих точек на _cubCol[dCol][dRow]~=nil, так как проверяются их свойства перед добавлением в контейнер. Но думаю с этим вы справитесь.